# Test that output does not contain text

Tags: phpunit

I know how to test php output with PHPUnit library, using `expectOutputString()` or `expectOutputString()`. Now I need to be sure that output doesn't contain given string. I can do this using output buffering and searching for string inside but probably better way is to use `expectOutputString()` with proper expression.

How should this expression be built?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to use a regex, and to do a negative match you have to use the lookahead assertion syntax. E.g. to test that the output does not contain "hello":

```
class OutputRegexTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    private $regex='/^((?!Hello).)*$/s';

    public function testExpectNoHelloAtFrontFails()
    {
        $this->expectOutputRegex($this->regex);
        echo "Hello World!\nAnother sentence\nAnd more!";
    }

    public function testExpectNoHelloInMiddleFails()
    {
        $this->expectOutputRegex($this->regex);
        echo "This is Hello World!\nAnother sentence\nAnd more!";
    }

    public function testExpectNoHelloAtEndFails()
    {
        $this->expectOutputRegex($this->regex);
        echo "A final Hello";
    }

    public function testExpectNoHello()
    {
        $this->expectOutputRegex($this->regex);
        echo "What a strange world!\nAnother sentence\nAnd more!";
    }
}
```

Gives this output:

```
$ phpunit testOutputRegex.php 
PHPUnit 3.6.12 by Sebastian Bergmann.

FFF.

Time: 0 seconds, Memory: 4.25Mb

There were 3 failures:

1) OutputRegexTest::testExpectNoHelloAtFrontFails
Failed asserting that 'Hello World!
Another sentence
And more!' matches PCRE pattern "/^((?!Hello).)*$/s".


2) OutputRegexTest::testExpectNoHelloInMiddleFails
Failed asserting that 'This is Hello World!
Another sentence
And more!' matches PCRE pattern "/^((?!Hello).)*$/s".


3) OutputRegexTest::testExpectNoHelloAtEndFails
Failed asserting that 'A final Hello' matches PCRE pattern "/^((?!Hello).)*$/s".


FAILURES!
Tests: 4, Assertions: 4, Failures: 3.
```

Comment: Unfortunately this seems not to work with multiline. Please use `echo "What a strange world!\nNew sentence";` inside `testExpectNoHello()`

Comment: @koral Aha, you need the `s` flag in the regex. I've edited my answer, as this is typically what you'll want.

Comment: `echo "What Hello a strange world!\n";` doesn't give me failure :(

Comment: @koral You're right. Some study of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-string-not-containing-a-word told me I had the wrong regex. The `*` should've been outside the brackets! I've expanded my answer with two more tests.

Answer (score 6):

This is very simple. Test that string does not contain other string:

In 2024 for PHPUnit 11.x there is another concise approach:

```php
$this->assertStringNotContainsString(needle, haystack);
```

See PHPUnit [assertion doc](https://docs.phpunit.de/en/11.0/assertions.html#assertstringcontainsstring).

The other way, more verbose, more flexible with different assertions not only for strings:

```
$string='just some string'; 
$this->assertThat($string, $this->logicalNot($this->stringContains('script')));
// Assertion is passed.
```

Based on the great example of multiple assertions in the same test from http://www.kreamer.org/phpunit-cookbook/1.0/assertions/use-multiple-assertions-in-one-test

Meanwhile not all available assertions are documented in the docs, e.g. the above `assertStringNotContainsString` is not. The good way to find these is to `dd($this)` for Laravel (or `var_dump($this)` in pure PHP) from within your PHPUnit test class and scroll through the output's `methods` section. There you see the available assertions including the undocumented ones.

Comment: Not sure if @koral agrees or not, but I think in 2024 `assertStringNotContainsString()` is the correct answer.